# Post drop down select value in HTML form

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get drop down select value posted upon send.

Markup

```
<select name="taskOption">
<option value="1">First</option>
<option value="2">Second</option>
<option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
```

php

```
$selectOption = $_POST['taskOption'];
                    {
                      $message.=$value.'<br>';
                    }
                    $message.='
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the <form> to your code? You may be using GET instead of POST.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
if(!empty($_POST['taskOption']))
{
    $value = $_POST['taskOption'];
    $message.=$value.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `post` in your `form`, `method="post"`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $dropdwon = $_POST['taskOption'];
   //code here
 }
```